# Python Import Folder of .jpeg files

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jpeg

I'm trying to learn image classification in python using tensorflow, and I'm unsure of how to read in my folder of images. I have a training set of over 10,000 .jpeg images. I have been working with the MNIST tutorial and others, but I don't see any information on importing an entire folder without creating an array of all the images by each image path (which is not possible at this size). Any suggestions?

Comment: There must be a function that should help you list all the files of a given relative and/or absolute path. :)

Comment: Why "is not possible at this size"? When you load mnist you load into your memory thousands of images, why you cannot do the same by simply creating a np.zeros array and filling it by iterating over each image in the folder? What is the difference between this and an hypothetic function load_images_from_(folder)? At the end you have in the memory the same right?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Dataset object (added in TF 1.4+).

To get started you should read the well-written developers guide on the new input pipeline.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

In particular, you want to use `list_files` to generate a dataset of all your file names:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*.jpg')
```

Now you can use those files to load the images:

```
ds = ds.map(map_func=load_image)
```

The `load_image` function should accept a tensor (the file name) and output a tensor (the image in tensorflow form)

Something like this:

```
def load_image(filename_tensor):
  return tf.image.decode_jpeg(filename_tensor)
```

That function may need to be expanded a bit, and you might want to add data augmentation in there, so consider that the core skeleton of what you need.

When you've done that you create an iterator to read data. Definitely read the programmers guide referenced above. The last example on the page there is nearly exactly what you want. It's a nice data input pipeline and the way things are going in the future for Tensorflow.

Notice that using the Dataset pipeline means you won't need to pass the images into tenorflow via `sess.run`'s `feed_dict` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob
import numpy as np
globs = glob.glob('./test/*')

import PIL.Image as img

def img_array(path):
    image = img.open(path)
    tmp = np.array(image)
    image.close()
    return tmp

np.array(list(map(img_array, globs)))
```

open it with pillow and convert it to numpy array and map all arrays into one list.

`out:`

```
array([[[226, 245, 252],
        [227, 246, 253],
        [228, 247, 254],
        ...,
```

Comment: This is not an efficient way to feed data into Tensorflow.

Comment: it may be any framework, it should iterate and get the data.